# ActiveMQ client blocking, temp storage usage in ActiveMQ reaches 100%

Tags: activemq-classic

I am seeing 100% temp usage in ActiveMQ 5.15.3 while the store usage is just 29%.

Am using virtual topics and Queues and all messages are persistent.

I'm not sure why activeMQ is using temp storage..(temp is for storing non-persistent messages)

ActiveMQ is using mKahaDB as storage..

```
<persistenceAdapter>
 <mKahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb">
  <filteredPersistenceAdapters>
   <filteredKahaDB perDestination="true" >
     <persistenceAdapter>
       <kahaDB journalMaxFileLength="32mb" />
     </persistenceAdapter>
   </filteredKahaDB>
  </filteredPersistenceAdapters>
 </mKahaDB>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

Am not sure why this is happening ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem.

ActiveMQ had **File based Cursor** enabled which was using the temp storage and eventually going upto 100% and then the activeMQ was stalling. After disabling it, the temp storage is not used for persistent messages.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ signals other brokers via topics and queues. These are generally non-persistent. The best thing to do would be to make a copy of the db and open it up to look at the content of the store.

Comment: Jonathan : I opened up the log files from tmp_storage folder.. It has the messages of the virtual topic. But Ideally those shouldn't have ended up on the tmp_storage as they are persistent messages if my understanding of activemq goes right. What I mean is these messages should have been on the store instead of the tmp.But, I can't figure out why?

Comment: hmm, I would turn on some AMQ logging or tcpdumping and verify your messages that are being sent are truely marked as persistent. Also, you might post your activemq.xml